# UML diagram - Composition

Tags: uml, diagram, composition

Could someone help me out with this UML diagram?

[image: UML Diagram]

Given this UML diagram, suppose that at runtime, we have created objects a1 and a2 from class A, b1 and b2 from class B, c1 and c2 from class C, d1 and d2 from class D, e1 and e2 from class E. Which one of these situations could happen at runtime?

**a.** e1 contains d1, and d1 contains e2, and e2 contains b2

**b.** a1 contains c1, and c1 contains d1

**c.** b1 contains d1, and d1 contains e2

**d.** c1 contains a1, and a1 contains b1

I haven't been able to solve this, as I tend to think that both b) and d) are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a) is the correct answer.**

b) is false, as a1 can't contain anything

c) is false, because b1 can't contain anything

d) is false, a1 can't contain anything

**Description: C and it's children (D,E) can contain any class of this hierarchy as it can contain children of A**

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But one question, though: why can C, D and E contain any class of the hierarchy? Is it because of the composition?

Comment: It can contain instances of A (A and all it's subtypes) because the composition regarding A